# Cannot install the development version of terra

Tags: r, gdal, install.packages, terra

I want to install the development version of `terra` from `R-universe` in `R`:

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘terra’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘terra’

trying URL 'https://rspatial.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/terra_1.5-48.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1295679 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
** using staged installation
configure: CC: clang -arch arm64
configure: CXX: clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/terra’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/terra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/08/mh1pttl10bb9smhd8pl4gjyr0000gn/T/RtmpDvgaMN/downloaded_packages’
```

Session information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.2.0  fastmap_1.1.0   cli_3.3.0       htmltools_0.5.2 tools_4.2.0     yaml_2.3.5      rmarkdown_2.13  knitr_1.38     
 [9] xfun_0.30       digest_0.6.29   rlang_1.0.2     evaluate_0.15
```

I have `gdal`:

```
% gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.5.0, released 2022/05/10
```

Comment: Do you have gdal already installed? `gdal-config` is where your error is arising

Comment: @camille yes :). before running the `r` code I did: `brew install gdal ` and `brew install pkg-config`

Comment: Mac OS? If you have gdal installed, use the following:

Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")
remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")

Comment: @ramen it gives the same error

Comment: Another thing which comes to my mind - see this thread: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/522

Comment: On *nix (ubuntu in my case): `sapi@t5810:~$ dpkg -S gdal-config` which gives `libgdal-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/gdal-config.1.gz` and `libgdal-dev: /usr/bin/gdal-config`. So, you have to install libgdal-dev in addition to gdal itself.